# Umbraco 7 content keeps getting cleared

Tags: .net, umbraco

I've built a website in Umbraco 7 and at the end of every day the page content keeps getting cleared and im having to republish the entire site every day using http;//YOURDOMAIN/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true
I understand that the content is saved to a cache file but it seems like this cache file is getting cleared daily. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: are you using SQLCE?

Comment: Yeah I am using SQL CE

Comment: Take a look at this issue "Losing data when using IIS Express and SQL CE" http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621  and also https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/49713-Losing-data-on-server-restart . It has nothing to do with the publishing and the cache (which is for the front end not for the backoffice)